# Changing the name of an output file corresponding to an integer

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io

So, I am currently making a program in java, but I would like to make the program so that it changes the file output name corresponding to an integer in my class:

```
if(height > 10){
```

And here is my whole code

```
import java.awt.*;

public class imageReader {
    private BufferedImage img, imageOut;
    private int imageHeight, imageWidth;
    private int deepbkg;
    public imageReader() {

        initializeSet();
        readImage();
        ProcessImage();
        createOutImage();
        saveProcFile(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        imageReader iR= new imageReader();
    }

    public void initializeSet() {
        Color cold = new Color(250, 100, 200);
        deepbkg = cold.getRGB();
    }

    public  void readImage(){
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\David_tmp\\Desktop\\ProjectImages\\LongIslandforPrint.jpg"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {         
        }
    }

    public void ProcessImage(){
        imageHeight = img.getHeight();
        imageWidth = img.getWidth();
        System.out.println(imageHeight+ "  "+imageWidth );
    }

    public void createOutImage(){
        imageOut = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
        for (int imageX = 0; imageX < imageWidth; imageX++) {
            for (int imageY = 0; imageY < imageHeight; imageY++){
                int redbluevalue = img.getRGB(imageX, imageY);
                double height = getHeight(redbluevalue);
                // *****IMAGE HEIGHT****
                if(height > 10){
                    //***END OF HEIGHT****  

                    imageOut.setRGB(imageX, imageY, redbluevalue);
                }
                else{
                    imageOut.setRGB(imageX, imageY, deepbkg);   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveProcFile() {
        try {
            File outputfile = new      File("C:\\Users\\David_tmp\\Desktop\\ProjectImages\\LongIslandforrrrPrint.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(imageOut, "jpg", outputfile);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public double getHeight(int RGB) {
        double heightX =0.;
        Color tcol = new Color(RGB);
        int Red = tcol.getRed();
        int Blue = tcol.getBlue();
        int Green = tcol.getGreen();
        if( Red >248) {
            heightX = 81.+ 99 * ((double)Red/250.);
        }
        if( Red <= 7 ) {
            if(Green >= 249 ) // using blue  value to calculate height
                 // range 23 -81
            {
                heightX = 23. + 58. *((double)255 - Blue)/255.;
            }
            else               //using green to calculate height
            {
                heightX =   24.* ((double)Green-20.)/230.;  
            }
        }
        return heightX;
    }
}
```

so I would like

```
LongIslandforrrrPrint.jpg
```

To change on the integer here:

```
 if(height > 10){
```

So the file output would change corresponding to the integer

so the file name output would be like this

```
Heightmap[Integer].jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class imageReader {
private BufferedImage img, imageOut;
private int imageHeight, imageWidth;
private int deepbkg;
public imageReader() {

    initializeSet();
    readImage();
    ProcessImage();
    createOutImage();
    saveProcFile(); 
 }


public static void main(String[] args) {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
imageReader iR= new imageReader();
}
 public void initializeSet() {

Color cold = new Color(250, 100, 200);
deepbkg = cold.getRGB();
}
public  void readImage(){
try{
    img =
        ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\David_tmp\\Desktop\\ProjectImages\\LongIslandforPrint.jpg"));
}
catch (IOException e) {         
}
}
public void ProcessImage(){
imageHeight = img.getHeight();
imageWidth = img.getWidth();
System.out.println(imageHeight+ "  "+imageWidth );
}

public double myNum = 0;
public void createOutImage(){
    imageOut = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
    for (int imageX = 0; imageX < imageWidth; imageX++) {
        for (int imageY = 0; imageY < imageHeight; imageY++){
            int redbluevalue = img.getRGB(imageX, imageY);
            double height = getHeight(redbluevalue);
            // *****IMAGE HEIGHT****
            if(height > 10){
            //***END OF HEIGHT****  
                myNum = height;
                imageOut.setRGB(imageX, imageY, redbluevalue);
            }
            else{
                myNum = height;
                imageOut.setRGB(imageX, imageY, deepbkg);   
            }
        }
    }
}

public void saveProcFile(){
 try{
    File outputfile = new      File("C:\\Users\\David_tmp\\Desktop\\ProjectImages\\Heightmap["+ myNum + "].jpg");
    ImageIO.write(imageOut, "jpg", outputfile);
}
catch(IOException e) {
}
}   
public double getHeight(int RGB){
double heightX =0.;
Color tcol = new Color(RGB);
int Red = tcol.getRed();
int Blue = tcol.getBlue();
int Green = tcol.getGreen();
if( Red >248) {
heightX = 81.+ 99 * ((double)Red/250.);
}
if( Red <= 7 ){
if(Green >= 249 ) // using blue  value to calculate height
                 // range 23 -81
{
 heightX = 23. + 58. *((double)255 - Blue)/255.;
}
 else               //using green to calculate height
{  
heightX =   24.* ((double)Green-20.)/230.;  
} 
}
  return heightX;
}
}
```

Comment: Quick question, but how would I be able to use the variable that i specified?

Comment: What do you mean? The variable height? In my code it is assigned to the variable myNum and you can use it anywhere in your code apart from the main method.

Comment: ah, I skipped over that part, sorry

Comment: well, now you code doesn't work :\, I copied it over to my eclipse and well, I get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at reader.imageReader.ProcessImage(imageReader.java:42)
 at reader.imageReader.<init>(imageReader.java:18)
 at reader.imageReader.main(imageReader.java:26)

Comment: That probably means your LongIslandforPrint.jpg doesn't exist or the location path you've set for it is wrong.

Comment: Well, Im just gonna use string

Comment: Um, since the code dont work, mind telling me how I can use a string with this?